# How to add text before post_excerpt in Gutenberg

Tags: posts, excerpt, post-editor

I'm trying to edit my plugin to work on the updated version of the website.

I have a custom plugin, which worked with plugin [Post in Page](https://cs.wordpress.org/plugins/posts-in-page/) but not working with the integrated function of Gutenberg - Newest posts.

Added text is not showing before posts excerpts listed by integrated function. That's the problem I need help with. I didn't find any other `add_filter` example than my used one.

So let me show you my previous working code and I'm asking how to convert it to work with a new editor integrated function to list posts:

*This code is adding text hello world! before post excerpt.*

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'kamzici_custom_fields_display_init' );
function kamzici_custom_fields_display_init() {
    if (get_post_type() === 'page')
        add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'kamzici_custom_fields_display_content_filter', 20 );
}

function kamzici_custom_fields_display_content_filter( $content ) {
    $add_content = '<p>hello world!</p>';
    return $add_content.$content;
}
```

Is there any Gutenberg documentation, how to hook into it when I'm developing plugins? Just linking to documentation would help me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: [Website](https://karas-test-kamzici.vach.cz/) I need help with. Post "Štědrý den" should look the same after answering this question. Please be patient, that's only fork of original website, some playground for testing...

Comment: that filter has not changed, it should behave the same regardless of the editor used to create the post as it's a frontend filter, the theory that Gutenberg is the cause is unlikely

Comment: @TomJNowell I know that changing editor from Classic to Guttenberg doesn't do the issue when i use plugin Posts in page in both editors. But the question start's when I need to convert from Posts in page to Guttenberg method of printing post excerpts. How can I add text before post excerpts integrated at Guttenberg?

Comment: can you say that again but using different words? I think what you were trying to say was lost in translation and became ambiguous, e.g. what do you mean by "doesn't do the issue". Does this problem only affect the Post in page plugin? Is there a particular reason you're unable to migrate to the query block instead? There's a very high chance this is caused by the Post in Page plugin, have you opened a support ticket on .org? 3rd party plugin support questions are off topic here and not in this stacks scope

Comment: As for your question, you already have the answer, you are already using the canonical correct recommended way to add text to the start of an excerpt, the `the_excerpt` filter, though you're adding it in a very weird way, Gutenberg is not the cause of this, it's much more likely to be the unusual way the filter is being added on the template redirect hook. I suspect what you actually mean is not how to prefix an excerpt when using Gutenberg, but _how to prefix excerpts printed inside a specific shortcode_.